# How can I add 2 ints in a const definition in 1990?

Tags: c, macos, int, constants

Welcome to the 1990s,

I am using an old Mac os 7.01 API, and I need to define a "Rect" struct with an array of four constants. Sadly, I always get the "requires constant" error on that "Rect" definition. We are talking about a 24 year old compiler, though.

```
Rect shapeRect = {100, 100, 200, 200}; // Works

const int shapeSize = 10;
int shapeX = 0; // Cannot be const
int shapeY = 0; // Cannot be const

Rect shapeRect = {shapeX - shapeSize, shapeY - shapeSize, shapeX + shapeSize, shapeY + shapeSize }; // Error: "requires constant"
```

I've tried defining multiple const with all the 4 values calculated, but I still get the same error on the same line.

```
const shapeRectT = shapeX - shapeSize;
...

Rect shapeRect - {shapeRectT, ...};
```

My guess is that the shapeRectT const is not a constant? I am a beginner in C, but I believe this problem is probably easy to repair, but this is an old compiler, and things may be different, and I don't know if newer C standards changed things about this stuff.

EDIT: I found the documentation for this API (QuickDraw): https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/mac/pdf/ImagingWithQuickDraw.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to limitations of C89 that we all now have forgotten.

At that time you could not have non-litterals in the initializer of a global `struct` variable.  Non-litteral expressions were only allowed for local `struct` variables.

This restriction was due to the fact that the code execution really started in those time with `main()` (in fact a stub initializing stdin,stdout and the environment and then calling main).  There was no code generated for global initialisation.  Only values that where loaded as part of the image from the executable.

I just could confirm this behaviour with my old microsoft compiler. It was MSDOS, but from February 1990, so pretty close to the one you use:

```
struct R {int a, b; };  /* simple structure for the demo */ 

struct R a = { 1,2 };   /* global variable  with litteral init:  ok ! */  
const int v1 =10;       
const int v2 =20;   
struct R z = { v1,v2 };  /* Error message, "illegal initialization"  */

int main() 
{
struct R w = { v1,v2};  /* here it is accepted, because corresponding 
                           initialisation code could be generated/executed
                           as part of the function */  
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The initialization of `struct R z` is still invalid, even in C11.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference in aggregate (and union) initialization between C89 and C99. A quote from the [C99 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) (PDF page 95):

> The C89 Committee considered proposals for permitting automatic aggregate initializers to consist of a brace-enclosed series of arbitrary execution-time expressions, instead of just those usable for a translation-time static initializer. Rather than determine a set of rules which would avoid pathological cases and yet not seem too arbitrary, the C89 Committee elected to permit only static initializers. This was reconsidered and execution-time expressions are valid in C99.

Some C89 compilers implement this as extension. Yours doesn't. You can fix the error like this:

```
Rect shapeRect;
shapeRect.top = shapeX - shapeSize;
shapeRect.left = shapeY - shapeSize;
shapeRect.bottom = shapeX + shapeSize;
shapeRect.right = shapeY + shapeSize;
```

Comment: Thanks! I found the documentation for the API (QuickDraw), and I'll  use your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do it manually. (Not recommended.)
2. Make some constants you use for initializing (not `const`-qualified variables).

   ```
   enum {shapeX_Init = 0, shapeY_Init = 0, shapeSize_Init = 10};
   const int shapeSize = shapeSize_Init;
   int shapeX = shapeX_Init; // Cannot be const
   int shapeY = shapeY_Init; // Cannot be const

   Rect shapeRect = {shapeX_Init - shapeSize_Init, shapeY_Init - shapeSize_Init,
                     shapeX_Init + shapeSize_Init, shapeY_Init + shapeSize_Init };
   ```

Comment: I've tried this, but I still can't get what I want to do to work :/ I am trying to make shapeX_Init = shapeX, since shapeX gets changed over time. Sadly, I can't change constants obviously :/

I do think the API I am using must have a way to transform the Rect structs, but I did not find any documentation :/

Comment: You can use a compile-time-constant to initialize an object (maybe `const`-qualified) or create other constants, but never the other way around.